# Opening pages on button click based on ComboBox selection (Windows phone apps)

Tags: c#, xaml, combobox, windows-phone

Im currently learning windows phone application development. I have two Combobox lists. based on the selection made in combobox I need to open pages accordingly on clicking submit button. How can i do this using C# and xaml ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the SelectionChanged event handler within the ComboBox. It gets fired each time you select an item in the combobox. You can use this event to save the selected item that you require to navigate.

```
 private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
 {
        ComboBox cbx = (sender as ComboBox);
        var item = cbx.SelectedItem; // Gives you the selected item
 }
```